# Changing User Permissions Via Rally API

Tags: api, rally

Our workspace has created a new project which we wish to add all of our 1,000+ users to. This seems most easily done via a script interfacing with the API, rather than making the edits by hand, since Rally doesn't seem to offer a batch update function for user permissions. My question is, are user permissions even editable via the API? I've made changes to *user* records in the past, but not their permissions.

For context, I'm using Pyral to interface with the WSAPI.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely batch script User Permissions via the WSAPI.

While it's not written in Python, there is an open-source set of Ruby scripting tools built to do exactly this:

https://github.com/RallyTools/Rally-User-Management

You might want to check it out - if nothing else, the User Management scripts could provide good hints as to how to accomplish certain User updated/edits in pyral as well. Obviously the pyral mechanics would differ from those in the Ruby rally_api used by Rally-User-Management.